# Implications of ignoring CS1762 ("A reference was created to embedded interop assembly ... because of an indirect reference ...")

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

I'm in the process of resolving a bunch of warnings that have been accumulating on projects in an Excel addin. One such warning is the titular reference CS1762, because one reference imports embedded types and another doesn't (in my case, the specific `Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.v9.0` and `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel`, where the former does *not* embed interop types, and the latter does). I know that in order to resolve the warning, it's a simple matter of setting both to the same value.

However, I'm not clear on what the current behavior is (which I'd like to maintain). Specifically, is the warning stating **"You've asked me to copy only the interop details that matter for this assembly, but everything for this other assembly, so I've just copied everything in the end"**, or is it stating **"You've asked me to embed interop types for this assembly, so now I'm going to do that irrespective of other settings"**?

Intuitively, it should be the first, meaning to resolve the warning and keep current behavior, I should just set all cases of embed interop types to false. However, since I know that the addin is more or less working as is for all users, some of whom use Excel 2010 and some of whom use Excel 2013, and some of whom may explicitly have VSTO installed, and some of whom may not, I'd like to be sure that I'm not setting myself up for a bruising later on when some features of the addin stop working for no apparent reason due to changing the setting.

Of course, a third option is just to suppress the warning and let VS keep doing whatever it currently is, but this seems like the wrong approach.

Comment: You asked it to embed the interop types and it tells you that it can't do it *at all*.  So it didn't.  Should be noticeable in the project as well, the reference should have the Copy Local property to True and you must deploy both interop assemblies to make your addin work.

Comment: Interesting. It certainly seems to *think* it's going to embed them, though - changing the setting to false introduces a bunch of compile-time errors surrounding properties that look like they should be dynamic now returning object references. Something tells me a couple of dynamic casts won't hurt to fix those compiler errors, but surprising that it's needed.

Comment: "Bunch of compile-time errors" doesn't help us help you.  The only sane thing to do is to embed both.  You'll however might have to change code, you can't use the synthetic XxxxClass types anymore.  Simple to fix, use Xxxx instead.

Comment: Errors in question just imply various functions that had previously been returning e.g. `Excel.Range` instances now return `object` instances as far as Visual studio is concerned. I didn't elaborate, since I'm used to referring to nested properties in Excel within the immediate window using `((dynamic)(this.Application.ActiveWorkbook)).Cells[1,1].SomeProperty` syntax in order to make things work, so I suspect it'll end up being the same thing.

Comment: If you want to read the details of how the embedding works or want to create you own, here is the documentation on down-/upsides and how to do it yourself: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt632256.aspx